# An error is reported when the computing engine is created in the startup script: “Cannot recognize the token”

Tags: spark-streaming, dolphindb

When the table name specified in the function “enabletableshareandpersistence” is used as a parameter of dummytable in the createreactivestateengine, the error “Cannot recognize the token” will be reported. And this problem only occurs in the startup script, it won’t occur if running the code  in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB first parses a block of script for grammar checking. The parsing phase identifies errors such as undefined variables or missing function parameters, etc. The parsing phase also stores function definitions in memory for later use. After parsing, if there is no error, DolphinDB interprets the script line by line and executes the script.

The table shared by enableTableShareAndPersistence is generated at the execution stage, so createReactiveStateEngine cannot be used directly. You can use objByName to refer to the table, or add a go statement after enableTableShareAndPersistence.

The go statement divides the program into multiple code blocks. The system parses and executes code blocks in sections.